# Wait for asynctask to finish to upgrade the database

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After I create my database I use this code to perform some query:

```
    Database bd= new Database(this);

    .............

    bD.open();
    ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor query = bD.getData(my query goes here);
    MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, query, 0);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    bD.close();
```

This is working as expected.

Now, if I increase the number of my database version when the call is made to `bD.open()` since the new version number is higher, the `onUpgrade`method is called and

```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVesion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BD_TABLE);

            new UpgradeDb().execute(...some params here...);
    }
```

and I have this:

```
public class UpgradeDb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(String... params) {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progresso = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, params[0], params[1]);

        progresso.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        downloadDB(params[2], params[3]);
        return params[1];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dbInstalled) {
        getPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor pref = getPref.edit();


        pref.putBoolean(dbInstalled, true);
        pref.commit();

        progresso.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(null);
    }
}
```

UpgradeDb is a inner class of `public class Database extends Activity`. In this class I have the `private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` and `public class UpgradeDb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>`

I´me getting and `SQLite returned: error code = 1: msg = no such table .....'

I think that this is because `bD.open();` has dropped the tables and is still doing the upgrade while `Cursor query = bD.getData(my query goes here);` is already trying to access the data.

So my question is how can I solve this, that is, wait for the `asynctask` to finish?

Comment: UpgradeDb is separate class or inner class of any other class or Activity ?

Comment: Sorry. Is an inner class of `public class Database extends Activity`. In this class I have the `private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` and `public class UpgradeDb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>`

Comment: then what is issue just move     `ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor query = bD.getData(my query goes here);
    MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, query, 0);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    bD.close();`  inside onPostExecute if UpgradeDb is inner class of Database Activity?

Comment: Since that is used if the database is upgraded or not, it should stay where it is.

Comment: mean im not getting u . if u explain more what issue you are getting if you move adapter related code inside